# How to write in a Remote JMS-Queue from JBoss

Tags: java, jms, jboss7.x, activemq-classic

I'm using JBoss Wildfly and like to Produce messages in a remote (not embedded) JMS Queue (active-mq-5.9) from a Session Bean.

My Bean:

```
@Stateless
@ResourceAdapter("activemq-ra.rar")
public class FinancialLoggerBean implements FinancialLoggerRemote, ManagedBean {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FinancialLoggerBean.class.getName());

    @Resource(lookup = "jboss/ConnectionFactory")
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    @Resource(lookup = "jboss/queue/financialLogQueue")
    private Destination destination;

    private Connection connection;

    @EJB
    private FinancialLoggerBeanManager ejbManager;

    ...
}
```

I found some examples on the web how to configure the Link between jboss and active-mq via a resource adapter. In my standalone.xml I've configured the adapter like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.1">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter>
                    <archive>
                        activemq-rar.rar
                    </archive>
                    <transaction-support>XATransaction</transaction-support>
                    <config-property name="UseInboundSession">
                        false
                    </config-property>
                    <config-property name="ServerUrl">
                        failover:(tcp://127.0.0.1:61616)
                    </config-property>
                    <connection-definitions>
                        <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">
                            <xa-pool>
                            <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                            <prefill>true</prefill>
                      </xa-pool>
                        </connection-definition>
                    </connection-definitions>
                    <admin-objects>
                        <admin-object class-name="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue" jndi-name="java:jboss/queue/financialLogQueue" use-java-context="true" pool-name="financialLogPool">
                            <config-property name="PhysicalName">
                                financialLogQueue
                            </config-property>
                        </admin-object>
                    </admin-objects>
                </resource-adapter>
        </resource-adapters>
```

But the Resources cannot be linked to my bean. Something seems to be missing.

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."financiallogger-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT"."financiallogger-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT".FinancialLoggerBean.env.jboss.ConnectionFactory (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."financiallogger-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT"."financiallogger-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT".FinancialLoggerBean.env."myBeans.FinancialLoggerBean".connectionFactory] 
  service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."financiallogger-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT"."financiallogger-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT".FinancialLoggerBean.env.jboss.queue.financialLogQueue (missing) dependents: [service jboss.naming.context.java.comp."financiallogger-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT"."financiallogger-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT".FinancialLoggerBean.env."myBeans.FinancialLoggerBean".destination]
```

Any Hints?

Thanks,

Michel

Comment: I'm confused. It seems like you want to send a message to a remote (in other words: hosted on another machine) queue, don't you? Yet your configuration work seems to hint that you are setting up an ActiveMQ queue in the local JEE container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a config problem in your MQ module in your JBoss library management.